# USB-attached HDD visible in dmesg, but can't be opened with fdisk

Tags: hard-disk, usb-drive, fdisk

I've attached a SATA to my computer via a "plugable" (that's the company name) disk docking station. The docking station is fine, since I've attached another HDD and was able to see its partitions' contents.

Now, when I attach, I get:

```
[  +0.000604] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  +0.247332] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  +2.324092] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.020970] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[  +0.000004] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  +0.000003] usb 2-3: Product: USB3-SATA-UASP1
[  +0.000003] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Plugable
[  +0.000003] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 123456789096
[  +0.002430] scsi host7: uas
[ +11.433187] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access                               0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0.052283] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  +0.000101] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[  +0.000342] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[  +0.000006] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  +0.000153] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0.000201] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[  +0.001339] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

Note the error. If I try `fdisk /dev/sde`, I get:

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sde: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening, and is there a way I can fix/overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Note this line:

[  +0.052283] sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)

The disk is reporting its size as **zero** blocks!

You might want to check the disk's SMART health information with `smartctl -a /dev/sde` or similar. I think you'll find that the disk's internal diagnostics indicate the disk has failed, and that will be the reason the disk reports its size as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

What you should have seen is a message like

```
sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

This would have created `/dev/sde`.

I suspect the whole thing happens in the kernel code, and the kernel code seems to rely on the `Synchronize Cache` SCSI.

You can verify this by looking at the code in the kernel source. If it is as I suspect, there's no way to fix it except rewrite the kernel code (or ask the kernel developers).

You can also install `sg3-utils`, issue the `Synchronize Cache (10)` command manually and see what goes wrong, and also try to read some blocks directly with SCSI commands. If this also doesn't work, then the problem isn't that the `Synchronize Cache (10)` command isn't supported by your particular disk, but that something else on a lower level goes wrong.

Comment: I got that too, sorry. I've pasted a few more lines of the dmesg log.

Comment: So do `ll /dev/sde` and see if the device node exist. If it doesn't exist, it may have been removed by the kernel - are there possibly more relevant lines in `dmesg` you are not showing us? But with 0 blocks and the cache command failing I suspect a problem on the transport layer somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

This is a error in fdisk, to fix it simply change the current directory to the **/dev** directory with **cd /dev** and then you can use **fdisk** while in the **/dev** directory.

Once you are in the **/dev** directory you can now type **fdisk /dev/sde** and it should work.

Comment: How can you be so sure?

Comment: Happends too me every time i use fdisk and i tried troubleshooting it and it lead me to this answer, why not try it and see for yourself